# Highslide shrink popup with browser size

Tags: layout, liquid, highslide

Am using Highslide with liquid layout. How can I change code to have popup size to a percentage of browser window?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t use percentage for the size of a Highslide popup.

- A regular Highslide image popup will show the image in its full size,
  but the image will shrink to fit the viewport if the image is larger
  than the viewport and [allowSizeReduction](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.allowSizeReduction) is true (default
  setting).
- If [useBox](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.useBox) is true, you need a fixed [width](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.width) and [height](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.height)
  (in px) for the image area.
- HTML popups needs a fixed width. Default width is 400px.

Comment: It works fine as is. If I start with a "shrunken" browser window--it sizes to window. Thank you very much.